# (Q,+) and (C*,+) has no finite index subgroup

Tags: group-theory

How to prove ($\mathbb Q$,+) and ($\mathbb C^*$,+) has no finite index subgroup?

Comment: Did you mean $(\mathbb C^*,*)$?  Or $(\mathbb C,+)$?

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice exercise telling that if $G$ is a divisible group then every non-zero quotient group of it is infinite and vice-versa. Assuming you know the [divisibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) for abelian groups, you can apply this fact.